# How can i implement coalesce query in django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to build an ecom website using django and djngo rest framework. My model Item contains price and sale_price column:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField()
    sale_price = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
```

I want to filter them by max active price
So in order to do that in sqlite i would write something like

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE coalesce(sale_price,price) < maxPrice;
```

How can i do this in Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has a [**`Coalesce`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) function. You thus can filter for example on:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Item.objects.annotate(
    real_price=Coalesce('sale_price', 'price')
).filter(
    real_price__lt=maxPrice
)
```

or if you want the largest of the two, it is best to use:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Item.objects.annotate(
    real_price=Greatest(Coalesce('sale_price', 'price'), 'price')
).filter(
    real_price__lt=maxPrice
)
```

The way `NULL`s are handled in a greatest expression differ from database to database. For example SQLite will return `NULL` from the moment one of the parameters is `NULL`.

Comment: I don't  understand why use `Coalesce` instead of `Greatest`

Comment: @minglyu: `Coalesce` checks if the first item is `NULL`, if it is, it moves to the next one. `Greatest` on the other hand will return something different if both values are not `NULL`, but `price` is greater than `sale_price`.

Comment: @minglyu: updated a case for the largest of the two. Note that `Greatest` will return `NULL` in SQLite if one of the parameters is `NULL`.